# Uploading Images to android Market. JSON response error, please disable it and refresh

Tags: android

When I try to upload an icon image o screen capture to android market for my app. Browser give me this error:

Unable to parse response. If you have a browser extension or add-on installedwhich changes the JSON response, please disable and refresh this page.

I've tried with Firefox and chrome...

Answer (score 0):

You need to pay the $25 or wait for transaction to clear. I was having the same problem it is nothing to do with the browser just need to make sure that you have paid Google.